# How to interpret result of kMeans scores if I have encoded the data with OneHotEncoder?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means, pca

I am working on the `AdventureWorks` database and I have extracted some demographic data from the `person` scheme as follow. My aim is to create a customer segmentation with the demographic data using the clustering technique.

| businessentityid | YearlyIncome | Education | Occupation | HomeOwnerFlag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1699 | 25001-50000 | Graduate Degree | Clerical | 1 |
| 1700 | 50001-75000 | Bachelors | Professional | 0 |

Because the dataframe contains categorical data, I have decided to encode it using `OneHotEncoder`. The resulting table is as follows. Note that the tables and dataframes provided is just a sample in order to illustrate the idea.

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
```

| YearlyIncome_0-25000 | YearlyIncome_25001-50000 | Education_Graduate Degree | Education_Bachelors | HomeOwnerFlag_0 | HomeOwnerFlag_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Later down the line, I used `Principal Component Analysis` to reduce the dimensions.

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
```

And then applied KMeans algorithm. I experimented with elbow method to find out that the 4 is optimal n value.

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
```

```
print(kmeans4.labels_)
```

```
array([0, 1, 3, ..., 1, 0, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Lastly, I combined the initial dataframe with the labels.

| businessentityid | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 1699 | 0 |
| 1700 | 1 |
| 1701 | 3 |

How do I interpret the labels?
There are four clusters but in the process of encoding with OneHotEncoder, the dimensions have increased and got complicated.
The PCA reduced the dimensions to 2 (could be different), but how do I know what label means what?
Is there something else to follow?

Comment: the labels are the clusters. so if your clustering is done correctly, entries with the same cluster labels should be very similar, like they share categories

Comment: Both PCA and K-means are methods generally not suitable for categorical data. Even if you turn your categories into dummy (one-hot) sets of variables. There is just no sense in doing that.